# Having issue reading a file from directory

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat7, bufferedreader, filereader

I have csv file and when i try to read from the following code it throws an error FileNotFound. Can someone please suggest the solution for this.

```
    String csvFile = "spring/batch/report.csv";
    BufferedReader bufferReader = null;
    String line = "";
    String cvsSplitBy = ",";
    try {

        System.out.println("Job A has been started................");
        bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {

            // use comma as separator
            String[] country = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

            System.out.println("Country [code= " + country[4] + " , name="
                    + country[5] + "]");
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the full path of csv file. 
Like

```
String csvFile = "C:/temp/abc.csv";
```

Comment: Actually I have placed this file in resource filepath. for exmp "resources\spring\batch".

Comment: If it's a resource you should not attempt to access it using java.io.File objects or its derivatives. You should access it via the ClassLoader instead.